# Does $X$ have a lower bound?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $P=\{A \subseteq \mathbb N: A$ is non-empty, finite and has an even number of elements$\}$. Consider $X=\{A \in P : 1 \in A\}$. Does $X$ have a lower bound in $(P,\subseteq)$?

I think that there is a lower bound.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: consider $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$.